# Unable to extract reactive values in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, reactive, shiny-server

I get an error message when I run my server function that says: **"Error : Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.

- You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer."**

Can anyone tell me why my reactive code is producing that error?

**Here is my NON-reactive server:**

```
server <- function(input, output){
  reactivedata <- reactive({PC 
  })
  x <- reactive({reactivedata() %>% drop_na() %>% pull(plotdate)})
  y <- reactive({
    reactivedata() %>% pull(Value) %>% na.omit()
  })
  
  ###Non-reactive code
  
  for (d in 1:c){
    tempval <- val[which(!is.na(val[,d])),d] #omit not filled rows na
    tempdate <- rollingdates[,d]
    se <- sd(tempval)
    mean <- mean(tempval)
    movrang <- diff(tempval)
    rbar <- mean(abs(movrang))
    d2constant <- 1.1283791671
    sigmacalc <- rbar/d2constant

    if (percent1 >= 0.02){
      rc <- rc + 1
      if (!is.na(usl) && !is.na(lsl) == TRUE){
        ppkcalc <- c(((usl-mean)/(3*sigmacalc)),((mean-lsl)/(3*sigmacalc)))
        ppk <- min(ppkcalc)
      }else if (is.na(usl) == TRUE){
        ppk <- ((mean-lsl)/(3*sigmacalc))
      }else if (is.na(lsl) == TRUE){
        ppk <- ((usl-mean)/(3*sigmacalc))
      }

      PC$Parameter[rc] <- param
      PC$Calculation[rc] <- "ppk"
      PC$Value[rc] <- ppk
      PC$DateRangeBeg[rc] <- as.character(tempdate[length(which(!is.na(tempdate)))])
      PC$DateRangeEnd[rc] <- as.character(rollingdates[1,d])
      PC$plotdate <- paste(PC$DateRangeBeg, PC$DateRangeEnd, sep="  ")
    }
  }
  PC = na.omit(PC)
}
```

Here is pretty much the same code, but made in a reactive form (I am reactively extracting the usl, lsl, ucl, and lcl values.
**Here is my REACTIVE server:**

```
server <- function(input, output){
  reactivedata <- reactive({PC 
  })
  x <- reactive({reactivedata() %>% drop_na() %>% pull(plotdate)})
  y <- reactive({
    reactivedata() %>% pull(Value) %>% na.omit()
  })
 
  
  ###Reactive Code 

  
  ucl =reactive({excel[excel$Quality.Attributes == input$select, "UCL"]})
  lcl =reactive({excel[excel$Quality.Attributes == input$select, "LCL"]})
  usl =reactive({excel[excel$Quality.Attributes == input$select, "USL"]})
  lsl =reactive({excel[excel$Quality.Attributes == input$select, "LSL"]})
  # #
  # 
  # 
  for (d in 1:c){
     tempval <- val[which(!is.na(val[,d])),d] #omit not filled rows na
     tempdate <- rollingdates[,d]
     se <- sd(tempval)
     mean <- mean(tempval)
     movrang <- diff(tempval)
     rbar <- mean(abs(movrang))
     d2constant <- 1.1283791671
     sigmacalc <- rbar/d2constant
      
   if (percent1 >= 0.02){
       rc <- rc + 1
     if (!is.na(usl()) && !is.na(lsl()) == TRUE){
     ppkcalc <- c((usl()-mean/(3*sigmacalc)),((mean-lsl())/(3*sigmacalc)))
       ppk <- min(cpkcalc)
     }else if (is.na(usl()) == TRUE){
       ppk <- ((mean-lsl())/(3*sigmacalc))
     }else if (is.na(lsl()) == TRUE){
       ppk <- ((usl()-mean)/(3*sigmacalc))
    }
  # 
  # 
       PC$Parameter[rc] <- param
       PC$Calculation[rc] <- "ppk"
       PC$Value[rc] <- ppk
       PC$DateRangeBeg[rc] <- as.character(tempdate[length(which(!is.na(tempdate)))])
       PC$DateRangeEnd[rc] <- as.character(rollingdates[1,d])
       PC$plotdate <- paste(PC$DateRangeBeg, PC$DateRangeEnd, sep="  ")
   }
   }
   PC = na.omit(PC)
}
```

Comment: I think your whole for loops should be in a reactive context, i.e an `observe` or `observeEvent`

Comment: Without a fully standalone reproducible example, it will be guesswork, but what happens if you move all the code inside the `server` function?